# Change view height instead of ScrollView bouncing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a swiftUI view that contains a scrollView. This scroll view contains a bunch of views:

```
    public var body: some View {
    MainScrollView(scrollStore: feedScrollStore) {
        VStack {
            logoView
                .frame(height: 50)
            mainComponents
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    }
}
```

`mainComponents` is just an array that contains bunch of views.

My scroll view bounds, that is important.
Now I have a scenario when I need to disable bounds and increase height of `logoView` in other words I have to immitate a bouncing but with the logoView so I could set some custom animations to the logo whe user tryes to scroll down when the scrollView is on the top.

How could I do that with swiftUI? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance